# Error while fetching data from firestore using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, widget

Have tried almost all the solutions from stack overflow
I am able to write data in the firestore but after implementing the fetch function I am not able to fetch the data that I uploaded

What I expect to do is:
I have uploaded a form user input data in the firestore and want to fetch those data from firestore

**If you want you can find the link to entire code [here](https://github.com/Prat15072000/neelam)**

**Here's the error:**

```
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'data'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: data
Found: data() => Map<String, dynamic>
```

**Here's a quick snapshot of all methods that I have written so far**

```
String name, age, phone;
  crudMethods crudObjs = crudMethods();
  QuerySnapshot rideNow;
  List userProfilesList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    fetchDatabaseList();
    super.initState();
  }

  fetchDatabaseList() async {
    dynamic resultant = await crudMethods().getData();

    if (resultant == null) {
      print('Unable to retrieve');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        userProfilesList = resultant;
      });
    }
  }

body: Column(children[
 Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: userProfilesList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(userProfilesList[i].data['name']),
                      subtitle: Text(userProfilesList[i].data['age']),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            
]);
```

**Here's the fetch data method:**

```
Future getData() async {
    List itemsList = [];
    final CollectionReference profileList =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Ride Now Details');
    try {
      await profileList.get().then((querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
          itemsList.add(element.data);
        });
      });
      return itemsList;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

If you have a better way around by which I can fetch the data can please help me out with this and please help me solve this error.

Answer (score 3):

`data` is a method, not a property.  So you have to call it like a method.

```
itemsList.add(element.data());
```

As you can see from the [API documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html), it returns an `Map<String, dynamic>` with the fields and values in the [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html).

Comment: Could you also highlight the same in the above-mentioned code cause I am performing a get operation instead of add and also am new to it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.  If you have a new question, please post it separately.

Comment: What exactly should I have to change in order to get the desired result that's it.

Comment: Look carefully at the line of code I provided.  I'm calling data() as a method with parenthesis.